# Kotlin Multiplatform library for iOS with bitcode

Tags: ios, kotlin, ios-frameworks, bitcode, kotlin-multiplatform

we use Kotlin to share a library between Android and iOS.

We set up everything, but on iOS i need Bitcode enabled.
After a research I found solution:

```
kotlin {
targets {
    fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'jvm') {
        mavenPublication {
            artifactId = 'my-lib-name'
        }
    }
    // Switch here to presets.iosArm64 to build library for iPhone device || iosX64 for emulator
    fromPreset(presets.iosArm64, 'iOS') {
        compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')
        compilations.main.extraOpts '-Xembed-bitcode' // for release binaries
        compilations.main.extraOpts '-Xembed-bitcode-marker'//  for debug binaries
    }
  }
}
```

But the question is now, do I have and if yes, how do I separate between release and debug binaries and the specific flags?
Can i simply add both flags without any drawbacks?

Maybe somebody can enlighten me
thanks

Answer (score 10):

Since Kotlin 1.3.20 bitcode embedding for iOS frameworks works out of the box. You also can configure embedding manually if you need:

```
kotlin {
    iosArm64("ios") {
        binaries {
            framework {
                // The following embedding modes are available:
                //   - "marker"  - Embed placeholder LLVM IR data as a marker.
                //                 Has the same effect as '-Xembed-bitcode-marker.'
                //   - "bitcode" - Embed LLVM IR bitcode as data.
                //                 Has the same effect as the '-Xembed-bitcode'.
                //   - "disable" - Don't embed LLVM IR bitcode.
                embedBitcode("marker")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I disable bitcode generation using groovy in 1.3.20?

Answer (score 5):

Currently, all of the binary link tasks for the same iOS target share the compiler and linker options, so there's no way to setup the options for them separately. Please follow [KT-26887](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26887) for updates.

If you can afford running several builds with different options, you can set the options conditionally and run the build with a flag:

```
compilations.main.outputKinds('FRAMEWORK')

if (project.findProperty("releaseFramework") == "true")
    compilations.main.extraOpts '-Xembed-bitcode' // for release binaries
else
    compilations.main.extraOpts '-Xembed-bitcode-marker'//  for debug binaries
```

Then run the build with or without the flag, respectively:

```
./gradlew linkDebugFrameworkIOS
```

and

```
./gradlew linkReleaseFrameworkIOS -PreleaseFramework=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I only want to use Bitcode when it's actually needed. Xcode passes down an environment variable `ENABLE_BITCODE` which we can use to conditionally embed bitcode.

```
kotlin {
  iosArm64("ios") {
    binaries {
      framework {
        embedBitcode("YES".equals(System.getenv("ENABLE_BITCODE")) ? "bitcode" : "marker")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not completely correct, Xcode will set `ENABLE_BITCODE` for both debug and release builds, you should use `bitcode` only for release builds as it will slow down your compilation process, and `mark` for debug builds. If `ENABLE_BITCODE` is false (or not there) you should use `disable`, instead.

Comment: You can use the env var `CONFIGURATION` to know if is a debug or release build.

Comment: (By default there are 2 possible values for `CONFIGURATION`, "Debug" or "Release" but you can add more through Xcode, so check your project config...)